# How to create previews for PSD (Photoshop) images in SP 2013 images library?

Tags: image

If I upload images in PSD format (Adobe Photoshop) into a `SharePoint 2013` Images libary, there is no preview shown.

How can I create/activate previews also for such files formats like PSD files?

Answer (score 2):

photoshop file extentions are not supported within sharepoint as its a photoshop file. PSD files are complex full of layers, shadings ect and so the file is recognised by photoshop, hence why you cant preview the file!

the only one i know of is this 3rd party that allows support of psd file extentions.

http://www.finalcandidate.com/en/Pages/extractor10.aspx

sounds like alot of hassle! just store the psd file within a doc library but have the jpeg version for preview!

You could have two list that are connected to each other? one for psd one for jpeg (one to one relationship)